# Respond_to many AJAX calls from same controller

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs, respond-to

I have a page which has 2 or more lists which I want to paginate (with kaminari for instance)

`@list_a` and `@list_b`

these are being created in my `pages#home` controller

I want to have a link for each list (with `remote: true`) to append new elements via javascript.

That would make

```
respond_to do |format|
format.js
..
end
```

will fire a home.js.erb call.

but in home.js.erb I don't know how to know which link made the home.js.erb fire.

How do I differentiate between the 2 ajax links - from the controller or in the js? and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

in view file

```
<%= link_to "link_1", <your path>, :list => 1, remote: true %>
<%= link_to "link_2", <your path>, :list => 2, remote: true %>
```

in home.js.erb

```
<% if params[:list] == "1" %>
   // link 1 clicked
<% elsif params[:list] == "2" %>
   // link 2 clicked     
<% end %>
```

Comment: ah, so simple :). Will try it and let you know